# Xero: Something went wrong - previous state is different. CSRF prevention

Tags: xero-api

I am using WP Version 5.3.2 and WooCommerce version 3.7.0.

I am having issue with authenticating my site to Xero, using plugin, "WooCommerce Xero Integration", by WooCommerce – v1.7.24.

I've tested it with 3x Xero accounts but keep getting issue, **Something went wrong - previous state is different. CSRF prevention**.

I've created the app on Xero and have successfully pasted the key and secret details into the plugin.

Originally, it worked and then after disconnecting, it has failed to work ever since.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily disable or remove any extensions you're running.